# How to set DockWidget at Top Right corner of QGIS?

Tags: python, pyqt, qgis, qdockwidget

I am trying to dock my plugin window at the top right corner of QGIS but unable to place it at the top if there is a window already present.

I have used the following code which makes the plugin window to appear at the right side but not at the top as some other window is already present at the top.

```
dock_widget = QDockWidget("My_Plugin", self.iface.mainWindow())
dock_widget.setWidget(MainWindow)
dock_widget.setFixedWidth(356)
dock_widget.setFixedHeight(620)

self.iface.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock_widget)
dock_widget.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea | 
QtCore.Qt.TopDockWidgetArea)
```

Here is the example:

[image: example]

I want this Login Window above the Processing Toolbox, i.e., to be at the top right corner of QGIS and the Processing Toolbox should be below the Login Window.

Answer (score 0):

I use the below code to put my Pyqt5 application at bottom right corner of the screen. You may tweak some changes as per your requirement.

```
def location_on_the_screen(self):
    ag = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
    sg = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()

    widget = self.geometry()
    x = ag.width() - widget.width()
    y = 2 * ag.height() - sg.height() - widget.height()
    self.move(x, y)
```